# Passing an inherited complex type to a SOAP web service from PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, soap

I'm trying to call a legacy SOAP web service which accepts a complex inherited type as one of the parameters:

```
<s:complexType name="CreditCard">
 <s:complexContent mixed="false">
  <s:extension base="tns:PaymentCardBase">
   <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Cvv2" type="s:string"/>
   </s:sequence>
  </s:extension>
 </s:complexContent>
</s:complexType>

<s:complexType name="PaymentCardBase" abstract="true">
 <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CardHolderName" type="s:string"/>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CardNumber" type="s:string"/>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ExpiryDate" type="s:string"/>
 </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

And the call is:

```
<s:element name="DoStuff">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="accountNumber" type="s:string"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="paymentCard" type="tns:PaymentCardBase"/>
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

When calling it, I do this:

```
 $card = New-Object($type + ".CreditCard")
 $result = $cato.DoStuff("10024007", $card)
```

And the error is:

```
Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "CATO.CreditCard", for "DoStuff" to type "CATO.PaymentCardBase": 
"Cannot convert the "CATO.CreditCard" value of type "CATO.CreditCard" to type "CATO.PaymentCardBase"."

+ $result = $cato.DoStuff<<<< ("10024007", $card)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Comment: have you tried putting -as at the end of it? For instance, `$card = (New-Object($type + ".CreditCard") -as [YourNamespace.PaymentCardBase]`? Usually, as long as the type is part of the inheritance hierarchy, it's no problem, but you're also invoking the request from PowerShell.